# Choosing resistance in series with a photoresistor for best light-measurement resolution

Tags: led, sensor, photoresistor, light-sensor, resolution

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsE4uc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a photoresistor, R1, and as a voltage divider a fixed resistance, R2. There is a voltage of 5V over these two, and the voltage is measured over the photoresistor.

In my experiment I have a yellow LED on one side, a substance which I add blue color into, and the photoresistor on the other side. How do I decide what R2 to choose so that I can detect small changes in light (when increasing the opacity of the substance)?

Comment: @Oscar: Welcome to EE.SE. There's a built-in schematic tool in the editor. Sketch out what you've got, including part numbers. In your post add in the relevant specs. for the photoresistor and provide links to data sheets. Ignore rude people.

Comment: Also, can you measure the LDR (light-dependent resistor) resistance values for the extremes of your operating conditions? Connect the LDR leads directly to a multimeter on ohms range for the readings.

Comment: Consider a "Constant Current" source as R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a voltage divider circuit, sometimes incorrectly called a bridge.  The one fixed known resistor in series with the unknown resistance produces a voltage that is a function of the unknown resistance all the way from zero to infinity.  In theory, any resistance can be measured.

However, the sensitivity is greatest when the output voltage is in the middle of its range.  This is when the unknown resistance is close to the fixed resistance.  Therefore, use a fixed resistor (R2) that matches the photoresistor value in the middle of your typical experiment.  You can find this by disconnecting the photoresistor from the circuit and measuring it with a ohmmeter.  Or, you can pick different fixed resistors for R2 until you get about 2.5 V out for your typical setup.

Is the photoresistor really only 100 Ω when used in your experiment?  That's rather low.  2.5 V across this 100 Ω draws 25 mA and causes 63 mW dissipation in the photoresistor.  That shouldn't be a problem by itself, but will cause some self-heating, which probably changes the resistance a bit.  This means the resistance will change quickly due to light, then more slowly due to different dissipation at the different light level.

Photoresistors come in many different resistance ranges.  I would look for something more like 1 kΩ at the intended light level.

Comment: Usually such low-resistance sensors are not intended to be constantly powered: one would apply the voltage for a few milliseconds, read out the value then power the sensor down until the next measurement.

Comment: The photoresistor is not actually that low, the specifications read: 1 MΩ in darkness and 29 kΩ as typical resistance at 10 lux.

Comment: @OscarÅrling You get answers based on the information you provide. Providing accurate information leads to accurate and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage dividers have the best sensitivity when R1 is equal to R2. The voltage given by the divider is:
$$ V_x = V_1\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} $$

The sensitivity is given by the first derivative:
$$ d\frac{V_x}{dR_1} = V_1\frac{R_2}{(R_1+R_2)^2} $$

Assuming you will make your measurements at about 10 lux, your sensor resistance will be \$R_1=29k\Omega\$. Not surprisingly, the maximum of sensitivity function [occurs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+5x%2F%2829000%2Bx%29%5E2) when \$R_2=29k\Omega\$ as well.

Comment: I do not have access to a galvanometer, only resistances the photoresistor and the Arduino nano to provide and measure the voltages.

Comment: Ok, forget about Wheatstone bridge. Just pick R2 close to R1.